# Spelling mistake in Area 51 private beta email

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, email

> Good news everyone!
>
> The proposal to create a Chemistry Stack Exchange site has moved on to beta!
>
> This is a site for Scientists, academics, teachers and students.
>
> As one of 204 people who committed to the site, we need your help!
>
> We've granted you special access to a private beta preview, which you ***van*** visit at:
>
> http://chemistry.stackexchange.com

(emphasis mine)

Could someone please fix this in the Area 51 emails? Since a lot of the Area 51 commiters are SE newbies, this sort of makes a bad impression. Sort of.

*>>Hides from Jeff and his big S*

Comment: This should probably be reported on http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com, using "area51-meta" and "bug" as tags.

Comment: If you live in a van, that's how you *have* to visit beta sites

Comment: @kiam whoa, thought that that was the per-proposal meta only. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe this hadn't been caught until now. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Probably was caught, but everyone was hiding from Jeff's big 'S' I guess.